# How to check if list item is present on another list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to compare two lists (expected and actual) . I wanted to check whether expected list items are present in actual list items. I am trying the following sample code . I can try `set(expected)-set(actual)`.This will give me difference but i want to check if item is present else display which item is not present .Can someone guide me , how to achieve below expected result or what mistake i am doing.  Please ignore if there are mistakes as i am a learner.

```
actual = ['resources.sh', 'server.properties', 'resources.csv', 'resources.log', 'sampleresources.csv']
    expected = ['resources.sh', 'server.properties', 'resources.csv', 'resources.log']
    for i in expected:
        for b in actual:
            if b.split(".")[0] in i:
                print "{} is present".format(b)
            else:
                print "{} is not present".format(i)
```

Actual results:

```
resources.sh is present
resources.sh is not present
resources.csv is present
resources.log is present
resources.sh is not present
server.properties is not present
server.properties is present
server.properties is not present
server.properties is not present
server.properties is not present
resources.sh is present
resources.csv is not present
resources.csv is present
resources.log is present
resources.csv is not present
resources.sh is present
resources.log is not present
resources.csv is present
resources.log is present
resources.log is not present
```

Expected Result:

```
resources.sh is present
server.properties is present
resources.csv is present 
resources.log is present 
sampleresources.csv is not present
```

Comment: Are you after `set.intersection` ?

Comment: Thanks @JonClements . is this right approach ?    `if len(set(expected).intersection(set(actual))) > 0:
     print True
else:
     print False
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use list comrehension to have a cleaner code:

```
  actual = ['resources.sh', 'server.properties', 'resources.csv', 'resources.log', 'sampleresources.csv']
  expected = ['resources.sh', 'server.properties', 'resources.csv', 'resources.log']

  def print_msg(x):
      print(x,'is present')

  [print_msg(b) for i in actual for b in expected if i == b]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop through `actual` once:

```
for i in actual:
     if i in expected:
         print(i, "is present")
     else:
         print(i, "is not present")
```

Output:

```
resources.sh is present
server.properties is present
resources.csv is present
resources.log is present
sampleresources.csv is not present
```

Comment: Thanks for answer

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
actual = ['resources.sh', 'server.properties', 'resources.csv','resources.log', 'sampleresources.csv']
expected = ['resources.sh', 'server.properties', 'resources.csv',  'resources.log']
for i in actual:
    if i in expected:print "{} is present".format(i)
    else:print "{} is not present".format(i)
```

output:

```
resources.sh is present
server.properties is present
resources.csv is present
resources.log is present
sampleresources.csv is not present
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[print ("{} is present".format(b)) if b in expected  
else print("{} is not present".format(b)) for b in actual]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actual = ['resources.sh', 'server.properties', 'resources.csv', 'resources.log', 'sampleresources.csv']
expected = ['resources.sh', 'server.properties', 'resources.csv', 'resources.log']

result = [elem + ' is present' if elem in expected else elem + ' is not present' for elem in actual]
print result
```